# Most scalable approach to adding new data to a database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-design, scalability

I have a Rails website with three tables: User, Task, and TaskInstance. The Task table is like a master list of tasks, not coupled to any particular user, whereas the TaskInstance table contains records that indicate a user's completion of a particular task. In other words, a TaskInstance has a User id, a Task id, and a completion status (boolean). A User has many TaskInstances.

I'd like to allow administrators to add new Tasks. Doing so should create a new TaskInstance for that Task for every User. However, that doesn't sound like it would scale well. Say I have fifty thousand Users, creation of a new Task would require fifty thousand TaskInstances to be created immediately on the spot.

It would be good if some sort of lazy loading could be done instead, but I don't know where I would do it. I could do it at login e.g. when a User logs in, check if a new Task has been created; if so, create a new TaskInstance only for that particular User. But then what about users that are already logged in when the new Task is created?

I guess I'm just wondering what the preferred approach to this sort of problem is.

*Move this to the community wiki if you need to.*

Comment: If that user has not done anything with a Task he has no TaskInstance. So why create one upfront? Only create an instance if there is something to save.

Comment: But I want to be able to show the user their completed and non-completed tasks. If a TaskInstance does not exist for a particular Task, how would I show the completion status of that Task?

Comment: Just check if the TaskInstance for the User already exists - if not, then the user can't have completed it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't create the `TaskInstance`s right upfront, but only when they are needed. Since a new `Task` gets created anyway, it can be displayed to any User, no matter if there is a `TaskInstance` or not. As soon as a user decides to start with a `Task`, the `TaskInstance` should get instantiated.